# Javascript REGEX: How to get `1` and not `11`

Tags: javascript, regex

**If I do this:**

```
var string = "7,11,2"
var check = string.match("/1/");

if(check != null){
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

**Then `check` is not `null`** because `match` has found `1` in `11`. So how should I avoid this and get `1` when it really appears?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is happening because it matches a `1` in `11` and calls it a match. You have to make sure that there isn't another number following the 1. Try:

```
var check = string.match("/(^|\D)1(\D|$)/");
```

This will look for a way surrounded by characters that are not digits, or the start/end of string (the `^` and `$` anchors).

Comment: Thanks very much it works perfectly!! I will accept your answer as soon as I can!

Comment: this regex only works for this special case. see my upcomming answer for a regex to check if a value is in a somehow separeted list...

Comment: ah sure sorry, misread. just additionally gonna solve it with lookaround :D

Comment: @zolex Word of warning: JS doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: One suggestion (not relevant in this case, but in general): By using `/(^|\D)1(?=\D|$)/` instead, you'd allow this regex to match both `1` s in `1,1`. This would fail now because the comma is used up in the first match.

Comment: Cannot understand, I try the code above (with `1` inside the string) and still get `null`? `var string = "1,7,11,2"; var check = string.match("/(^|\D)1(\D|$)/"); if(check != null){ alert('found');} else { alert('not found');}`

Comment: Finally, the answer I've been looking for! Thanks @NullUserException

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to surround it with word boundary anchors: `/\b1\b/` will only match a `1` if it is not surrounded by other numbers, letters, or underscore. So it would work in your case (and is a bit more readable).

It will, however, fail in cases like ID1OT - if you wanted to extract the `1` from there, you could only do that with @NullUserException's method.